# Как остановить вложенный цикл?

Tags: delphi, циклы

Здравствуйте, в общем нужно сделать потоковый парсинг с проксями.

Я это делаю вот так:

```
procedure Parser.Execute;
var result:integer;
    razd:string;
begin
  razd := ';';
  while work do begin
   //code....

  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button3Click(Sender: TObject);
var
potok: integer;
begin
  id     := 0;
  work   := true;
  potok  := 5;

  for i:=0 to potok do
    Parser.Create(false);
end;
```

Вопрос как остановить цикл `FOR` когда находишься в процедура->цикл `while`?
И вообще правильно ли так делать потоки?

Comment: Поможет кто?

Comment: Уточните вопрос. Что у вас такое Parser (это TThread?), что значит остановить цикл (прервать или ждать окончания выполнения потока?). И чего вы хотите добиться и при каком условии.

Answer (score 1):

Ответ: НИКАК. 
`TThread` живет своей жизнью, а главный `VCL` поток своей. 
По сути, если будите тормозить цикл, пока не отработает поток. Толку будет мало.
Можно конечно `WaitForSingleObject` или `TThread.WaitFor`, но `VCL` поток при этом замрет в ожидании.

Пересмотреть реализацию проекта будет куда проще.

Comment: Так если у меня данные для проверки закончились в массиве, а потоки все еще есть? Что делать!?

Comment: пересмотреть реализацию. Вы сами себя загнали в угол. Реализация убогая, мало того, что потоки просто создаются и исчезают в никуда и не уничтожаются, так ещё и работают с глобальным массивом. 

Создайте TThreadManager класс, который контролирует потоки, при запуске берет массив, клонирует и делит между указанным кол-во потоков, далее ждет завершения всех потоков и уничтожает их.